# Dropdown results based on selection from previous dropdown

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel-5.8

I need some help to get more values on this dropdown filter.
I got 3 dropdowns, the first give me all "companies", the second, will show all "blocks" of that company, and the last one, will give me all rooms of that block.

So, I need to show 3 values on the last dropdown ('id', 'sala', 'name'). How do I do That?

Here how do i get the values to populate the last dropdown:

```
public function getAmbienteRev(Request $request)
{
        $ambientes = DB::table("ambientes")
            ->where("bloco_id",$request->bloco_id)
            ->orderByRaw("sala", "asc")
            ->pluck('sala', 'id');
        return response()->json($ambientes);
}
```

and here, the code who filter the values:

```
$('#unidade').change(function() {
   var unidadeID = $(this).val();
   if (unidadeID) {
       $.ajax({
           type: "GET",
           url: "{{url('get-bloco-rev')}}?unidade_id=" + unidadeID,
           success: function(res) {
               if (res) {
                   $("#bloco").empty();
                   $("#bloco").append('<option>Selecione o Bloco</option>');
                   $.each(res, function(key, value) {
                       $("#bloco").append('<option value="' + key + '">' + value + '</option>');
                   });

               } else {
                   $("#bloco").empty();
               }
           }
       });
   } else {
       $("#bloco").empty();
       $("#ambiente").empty();
   }
});
$('#bloco').on('change', function() {
   var blocoID = $(this).val();
   if (blocoID) {
       $.ajax({
           type: "GET",
           url: "{{url('get-ambiente-rev')}}?bloco_id=" + blocoID,
           success: function(res) {
               if (res) {
                   $("#ambiente").empty();
                   $("#ambiente").append('<option>Selecione a Sala</option>');
                   $.each(res, function(key, value) {
                       $("#ambiente").append('<option value="' + key + '">' + value + '</option>');
                   });

               } else {
                   $("#ambiente").empty();
               }
           }
       });
   } else {
       $("#ambiente").empty();
   }

 });
```

I need sommething like this:

```
    $.each(res, function(key, value, name) {
                   $("#ambiente").append('<option value="' + key + '">' + value + ' - ' + name +'</option>');
               });
```

I make this changes:

```
 ->pluck('name','sala', 'id')
```

and script to

```
$.each(res, function(key, value1, value2) {
                    console.log(res);
                       $("#ambiente").append('<option value="' + key + '">' + value1 + ' - ' + value2 + '</option>');
                   });
```

console.log(res)

```
 {101: "Sala de Aula", 102: "Sala de Aula", 103: "Lab de Criatividade e Inovaçăo", 105: "Atelier de Moda 2", 106: "Sala de Desenho 1", 107: "Sala de Aula", 109: "Sala de Aula", 110: "Sala de Aula", 113: "Sala de Aula", 114: "Atelier de Projeto 2 Design", 115: "Atelier de Projeto 3 Design", 116: "Atelier de Projeto 4 Design", 117: "Atelier de Projeto 5 Design", 118: "Atelier de Projeto 6 Design", 201: "Laboratorio de Simulaçăo e Projetos 1", 202: "Laboratório de Simulaçăo e Projetos 2", 203: "Laboratorio de Telecomunicaçőes", 204: "Laboratorio de Eletronica de Potencia", 206: "Sala de Aula", 207: "Laboratório de Eletrônica", 209: "Laboratório de Eletrônica", 210: "Sala de Aula", 213: "Espaço Fotográfico lab.fotogafico", 214: "Sala de Aula", 215: "Sala de Aula", 216: "Sala de Aula", 218: "Sala de Aula", 219: "Sala de Aula", 220: "Sala de Aula", 221: "Sala de Aula", 001: "Laboratório de Computaçăo 01", 002: "Laboratorio de Computaçăo 02", 002A: "Lab. de Informática 7", 002B: "Lab. de Informática 8", 002C: "Lab. de  Informatica 9", …}
```

But in Dropdown is showing

```
<option value="101">Sala de Aula - undefined</option>
```

Comment: Do a `console.log()` on `key` and `value`; see what they contain. You likely need to use object notation, like `value.sala` and `value.id` if that's what you're returning from your AJAX call.

Comment: @TimLewis, They return the id, and the number of the room, but I need to show also the name of the room. For example: ...value="1">001 - Meeting Room Red</option>

Comment: Please add the contents of `console.log(res)` to your question. It should be an array of JS objects, and each object should have the properties `sala` and `id` (as that's what you're plucking: `->pluck('sala', 'id');`)

Comment: Is that what you asked for?

Comment: Yes, but I'm not sure why it looks like that. Maybe don't use `->pluck()`? Replace with `->get()`, then in your function, you should have `function(index, ambient)`, and each `ambient` should be an object with `sala`, `id` and `name` available, like `ambient.sala`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem using a concat on controller.

```
        $ambientes = DB::table("ambientes")
            ->where("bloco_id",$request->bloco_id)
            ->orderByRaw("sala", "asc")
            ->pluck(DB::raw('CONCAT(sala," - ",name) AS name'),'id');
        return response()->json($ambientes);
```

tks